# permuting the rows and columns of a matrix for clustering

Tags: matrix, cluster-analysis, permutation

i have a distance matrix that is 1000x1000 in dimension and symmetric with 0s along the diagonal.  i want to form groupings of distances (clusters) by simultaneously reordering the rows and columns of the matrix.  this is like reordering a matrix before you visualize its clusters with a heatmap.  i feel like this should be an easy problem, but i am not having much luck finding code that does the permutations online.  can anyone help?

Comment: What does "online" mean here? In reference to clustering it usually means data are processed as they come in, rather than stored in memory all at once. But you have a 1000x1000 matrix, so that does not seem to be the case. If "online" means in a browser by means of javascript, then the problem is simply that of computing all pairwise row, resp. column similarities, followed by clustering. David's answer works; another algorithm, simple to implement (but benefiting from a more trickier and sparse implementation), is the Markov Cluster algorithm, which is used a lot in bioinformatics.

Comment: @micans, he meant he can't find it online = on the web.

Comment: @cyborg you're very likely right, that makes my comment moderately hilarious. user439463 seems to have left the conversation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 18):

Here is one approach that came to mind:

1. "Sparsify" the matrix so that only "sufficiently close" neighbors have a nonzero value in the matrix.
2. Use a [Cuthill-McKee algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm) to compress the bandwidth of the sparse matrix.
3. Do a symmetric reordering of the original matrix using the results from Step 2.

## Example

I will use Octave (everything I am doing should also work in Matlab) since it has a Reverse Cuthill-McKee (RCM) implementation built in.

First, we need to generate a distance matrix. This function creates a random set of points and their distance matrix:

```
function [x, y, A] = make_rand_dist_matrix(n)
  x = rand(n, 1);
  y = rand(n, 1);
  A = sqrt((repmat(x, 1, n) - repmat(x', n, 1)).^2 +
       (repmat(y, 1, n) - repmat(y', n, 1)).^2);
end
```

Let's use that to generate and visualize a 100-point example.

```
[x, y, A] = make_rand_dist_matrix(100);
surf(A);
```

Viewing the surface plot from above gets the image below (yours will be different, of course).

[image: Original distance matrix.]

Warm colors represent greater distances than cool colors. Row (or column, if you prefer) `i` in the matrix contains the distances between point `i` and all points. The distance between point `i` and point `j` is in entry `A(i, j)`. Our goal is to reorder the matrix so that the row corresponding to point `i` is near rows corresponding to points a short distance from `i`.

A simple way to sparsify `A` is to make all entries greater than some threshold zero, and that is what is done below, although more sophisticated approaches may prove more effective.

```
B = A < 0.2;   % sparsify A -- only values less than 0.2 are nonzeros in B
p = symrcm(B); % compute reordering by Reverse Cuthill-McKee
surf(A(p, p)); % visualize reordered distance matrix
```

[image: Reordered distance matrix.]

The matrix is now ordered in a way that brings nearby points closer together in the matrix. This result is not optimal, of course. Sparse matrix bandwidth compression is computed using heuristics, and RCM is a very simple approach. As I mentioned above, more sophisticated approaches for producing the sparse matrix may give better results, and different algorithms may also yield better results for the problem.

### Just for Fun

Another way to look at what happened is to plot the points and connect a pair of points if their corresponding rows in the matrix are adjacent. Your goal is to have the lines connecting pairs of points that are near each other. For a more dramatic effect, we use a larger set of points than above.

```
[x, y, A] = make_rand_dist_matrix(2000);
plot(x, y);   % plot the points in their initial, random order
```

[image: Data points and their original ordering.]

Clearly, connections are all over the place and are occurring over a wide variety of distances.

```
B = A < 0.2;     % sparsify A
p = symrcm(B);
plot(x(p), y(p)) % plot the reordered points
```

[image: Reordered data points.]

After reordering, the connections tend to be over much smaller distances and much more orderly.

Comment: Well presented answer, and both visualisations are very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Two Matlab functions do this: [symrcm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/symrcm.html) and
[symamd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/symamd.html).
Note that there is no unique solution to this problem. Clustering is another approach.